# Do breeding times match hatching times for dragons?

Tags: dragonvale

I am trying to find some meaning to the time it takes a dragon to breed and use that information to better guess what type of dragon egg to expect so I can prepare a proper habitat for it.

I have so far bred 3 dragons: Moss, Flower and Lava. The Lava dragon is hatching now and I have a 4th dragon being bred right now. The Moss dragon took 12 hours to breed, the flower took 1 hour and the Lava took 10 hours. These times match the hatching times for the eggs as well.

Does this always stand true? Even for rare and limited dragons? The dragon I have hatching right now is taking 14 hours. This matches a Tree dragon's hatching time. Am I going to get a Tree dragon or do I have a chance of getting the Clover Dragon I want (which hatches in 7 hours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the breeding time is always the same as hatching time for all dragons, rare dragons included. This means you can check your breeding time to know what dragon you're going to get; you're getting a Tree Dragon in this case.

You can verify the hatch/breeding time for any dragon with the Wiki's [Dragon Reference Chart](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Reference_Chart) to check which kind of dragon you might be expecting. Alternately you can just look in the store in-game. Look for dragons matching some/all of the elements of the Parents (combined) that have the same hatch time as your remaining Breeding time.

Note that the upgraded breeding cave/island reduce your breeding time by 20%, but the incubation time will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the breeding chart from the same Wiki site you linked to see what my possibilities were then checking them in game to see what the hatching times were :)

Comment: @BenBrocka This answer is slightly dated, given the introduction of upgraded breeding dens.  It is now possible to get a different breeding time than incubation time - but they are still related.  (Breeding time can be 20% less, with upgrade).

Comment: @EBongo thanks, updated that info, and linked to the proper wiki page, which apparently moved

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same unless you've upgraded the breeding cave or epic breeding island, and this is for all dragons - rares too!