# What can you get from breeding quake and willow in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

What can you get from breeding willow and quake and what are the corresponding incubation times?

Comment: That sounds like you got a crystal dragon (earth and lightning with a 24 hour incubation), but I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: That seems likely I have tried the combination before and crystal has been the outcome but this was one of the first times I peeked at the incubation time

Comment: @Nat There are few dragon's that require 24 hour breeding, and for the combination you've given Crystal is the only one.  I voted to close this question as "too localized" because while I'm sure it is interesting you you personally, it is pretty narrow in scope.  If you have similar questions for any pair you breed, there are calculators like [this one](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/).

Comment: @EBongo - Not sure I agree with this being too localized - it is simply the opposite of all the "How do I breed dragon X" questions, which we allow and are quite popular.  That being said, this would be a much better question if it was made more generic - i.e. given two dragons and an x breeding time, how do I determine what dragon I am going to get.

Comment: @Jason Berkan If the question were less localized, then I agree there would be no need to close as too localized. :). No telling if the OP would protest such an edit, it seems his original ask is specific.  Also, I believe [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59645/do-breeding-times-match-hatching-times-for-dragons) already covers that information. It could probably be freshened up a bit.

Comment: Why don't you _try and find out?_

Answer (score 1):

When breeding two dragons, you can get any dragon that contains the elements of the two dragons being bred, with the exception of elements that are opposites, as you usually need to breed a specific element with a hybrid of the opposite element to get those dragons.

That means that a Quake (Earth/Lightning) plus a Willow (Plant/Air) can breed any dragon that contains Earth, Lightning, Plant or Air, with the exception of the Earth/Air dragons, as Earth and Air are opposite elements.

That is [quite a large list](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/?1=Quake&2=Willow), but the only one with a 24 hour incubation time is the Crystal dragon as Fluttershy mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

During the Olympics only you can also breed an Olympus, most likely the Bronze Olympus as it is the most common of the Olympuses. If you get 35 hours you have either gotten a Gold, Silver, or Bronze Olympus dragon.